# iOS 7 Auto-renewable subscription expiration

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7, in-app-purchase

I am trying to check if an auto-renewable subscription is still valid on iOS7. The app receipt has the expiration date information for that subscription. After that period has passed, I want to refresh the app receipt to see if the subscription has been renewed and it is not expired.

**How should we refresh the app receipt without asking the user for his iTunes credentials?**

Both [restoreCompletedTransactions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPaymentQueue/restoreCompletedTransactions) and [SKReceiptRefreshRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKReceiptRefreshRequest_ClassRef/SKReceiptRefreshRequest.html) need the user's credentials.

From [Apple's "Working with Subscriptions" doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW3):

> After a subscription is successfully renewed, Store Kit adds a
>   transaction for the renewal to the transaction queue. **Your app checks
>   the transaction queue on launch**, and handles the renewal the same way
>   as any other transaction. **Note that if your app is already running
>   when the subscription renews the transaction observer is not called;
>   your app finds out about the renewal the next time it is launched**.

What does *checks the transaction queue on launch* mean? Any of the methods mentioned above I suppose, but then the app is requesting the user to enter his credentials.

In iOS7, we are not supposed to check against Apple Server's from the phone, it is all about checking the app's receipt, right?

By the way, I am developing in the testing environment. Is it possible the the app's receipt gets updated automatically in a real context? That would be the answer to my question then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All it means to check the transactions on launch is to call this once every time you run the app, not just before you make a purchase.

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:anObserver];
```

That way any renewals or interrupted/incomplete transactions can be handled.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, its built into the core of the OS, that is the only way you can do it.

The transaction queue is a list of things the user bought that the iOS is  still processing, when your app launches the store kit will go though this list and process it.

What apple mean is you are mean't to store it on your own sever and verify it that way. As in the past people just relied on Apple's Servers verifying it and then were attacked by a man in the middle attack which allowed hackers to get things for free.

I think you need to verify the receipt and when the subscription is updated I believe apple send your application a new one as soon as the user gives his details.